# How to send multiple mails with Android GmailSender

Tags: android, email

I'm trying to send multiple emails using GmailSender class on Android, where I add 3 mail contacts in sender.SendEmail builder. I tried to send using this implementation below, but did not work.

```
    private Boolean NotifyWithMail(String localFile)
    {
        Boolean ret = false;

        final GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("mymail@gmail.com", "******");

        try
        {
            ArrayList<Contato> colecao = new ConfigurationPreferences().
            if(colecao.size() < 1) return false;
            else
            {
                sender.addAttachment(localFile,"");//Anexo
                sender.sendMail("Alerta", "Movimento identificado no ambiente monitorado", 
                        "mymail@gmail.com",
                        colecao.get(0).getEmail().toString() + "; "
                                + colecao.get(1).getEmail().toString() + "; "
                                + colecao.get(2).getEmail().toString());

                ret = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ret = false;
            Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Performing tests, i will replace the ";" by "," to separate each email address and it worked.

**Final code**

```
sender.sendMail("Alerta", "Movimento identificado no ambiente monitorado", 
                        "mymail@gmail.com",                             
                        colecao.get(0).getEmail().toString() + ", "
                                + colecao.get(1).getEmail().toString() + ", "
                                + colecao.get(2).getEmail().toString());
```